# DetachedCriteria: Initialize Child's child

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a report with a section and each section have children.

And they are all set to lazy loaded.

May I know how to initialize those section's children?

I know how to initialize section

by using

```
.setFetchMode("section", FetchModel.JOIN)
```

but what about section's children?

Note: I do know how to use Hibernate.Initialization() but can DetachedCriteria perform it?

Answer (score 0):

in hibernate, when you try to use those collections, like parent.getChildren(), hibernate session will load the sub-entities at that time. so the name Lazy.
you dont have to init any collections, until it's specifically required by your use case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call this method within same transaction.

```
      Hibernate.initialize(parent.getChildren());
```

public static void initialize(Object proxy) throws HibernateException

Force initialization of a proxy or persistent collection.

Note: This only ensures intialization of a proxy object or collection; it is not guaranteed that the elements INSIDE the collection will be initialized/materialized.

Parameters:

```
     proxy - a persistable object, proxy, persistent collection or null
```

Throws:

```
    HibernateException - if we can't initialize the proxy at this time, eg. the Session was closed
```